# Declaring input_shape of a converted Sequence in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, nlp

I am trying to run a neural network on text inputs. This is a binary classification. Here is my working code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathname, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df = df[['content_cleaned', 'meaningful']] #Content cleaned: text, meaningful: label

X = df['content_cleaned']
y = df['meaningful']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21) 

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
X_train_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test_encoded = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

max_len = 100
X_train = pad_sequences(X_train_encoded, maxlen=max_len)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test_encoded, maxlen=max_len)


batch_size = 100
max_words = 100
input_dim = X_train.shape[1]  # Number of features
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))




model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, X_test,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=5,
                verbose=1,
                validation_split=0.1)
```

My question is two parts. First is with the `input_shape` when creating the layers. I am confused as to the syntax of declaring this. When running this command:

```
print(X_train.shape)
```

I am getting this shape: `(3609, 100)`.

From my understanding, this is telling me that there are 3609 instances. From viewing other examples, my naive assumption was to use the 100 as there are 100 types (may be understanding this incorrectly) corresponding to the `max_words` that I initialized. I believe that I may have done the syntax incorrectly when initializing the `input_shape`.

The second question is with an error message when running all of this (most likely with the incorrect `input_shape`). The error message highlights this line of code:

```
 validation_split=0.1)
```

The error message is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (1547, 1
```

Am I going about this problem incorrectly? I am very new to Deep Learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input_shape` argument specifies the shape of **one training sample**. Therefore, you need to set it to `X_train.shape[1:]` (i.e. ignore samples or batch axis):

```
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
```

Further, pass `X_train` and `y_train` to the `fit_generator` (instead of `X_train_encoded` and `X_test_encoded`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just ran this and it still highlights the same variable declared as "history". When highlighting that, it says points at the exact same line of code with the error which I have included in my last update to the original question.

Comment: So instead of running tokenizer.text_to_sequences, I do tokenizer.fit_generator?

Comment: @rmahesh No! I am referring to the fact that you are assigning the result of padding to `X_train` but instead you are using `X_train_encoded` in `model.fit_generator`. That's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response back. Please bear with me as I am trying to understand how to fix this error. I had the understanding that after splitting into train/test etc, you first convert the text to sequences, and then pad the sequences. In terms of variables, I first converted it to sequences, and stored results to “_encoded”. When doing the padding of sequences, I did this operation on “_encoded” and reassigned it to “X_train” etc. Should I have done this differently?

Comment: @rmahesh Ask yourself this question: "Do I want to train the model on the padded sequences or on the encoded sequences?" If you want to train it on the padded sequences then you should use the result of padding and pass it to `model.fit_generator`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As I mentioned, I am very new to this. I usually work backwards from code to figure out the logic. From all the examples that I have seen, the text was first converted to sequences, then padded. From your response, I am assuming that I should pick one or the other?

Comment: @rmahesh No, I am not saying that! The encoding and padding part is totally correct. It's just that you are **not** using the result of padding. Why? Because the result of padding is stored in `X_train`, however you are passing `X_train_encoded` to the `model.fit` method (I mistakenly referred to `fit_generator` in my comments above).

Comment: Wow I completely missed that. After fixing this error, I am prompted with the following error message (please see the edit above). Look forward to hearing back.

Comment: @rmahesh The second argument of `model.fit` must be the labels, which is `y_train` (not `X_test`).

Comment: That seemed to fix this issue thank you. I am prompted with another error with is irrelevant to the original question I asked. I will be posting a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You missed **two** ending parenthesis `)` at the line where you defined the input of your model. Also make sure that you provide your **activation function**.

Change your code as below:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],)))
```

**EDIT:**

For your last error just change your `input_shape` to  `input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, the exact same error is present when including that parenthesis.

Comment: After adding that extra bracket, I am faced with the following error code (which was why I was confident it had to do with the input_shape): "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (3609, 1)"

Comment: Edited with the latest error from the same code. It keeps highlighting the same thing with "validation_split=0.1)". Did I declare that wrong or something?

Comment: I already said what you should do. Change your `input_shape` to `input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],)`.

Comment: I have done exactly that and I am facing the error included in the edit above.